# Linux Bluez Bluetooth overload?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am working with a Raspberry Pi (running Jessie), Bluez, and iBeacons (10 iBeacons). My application (written in Python) sniffs for iBeacons and reports MAC address and RSSI. This is a continuous "sniff". The program can run for hours without any overload; however, after introducing a virtual iBeacon (from an iPhone app), the application seems to "overload" not allowing the application to be able to read the other non-virtual iBeacons forcing me to restart the Pi. Also, the virtual iBeacon is transmitting at MUCH faster rates as compared to the other iBeacons. Regardless, this poses a deployment problem as we cannot afford to have a rogue Bluetooth signal overloading the system.

Is this an issue with Bluez, the USB dongle (Iomega), or something else? Not posting code to the forum- interested in where to start looking for an issue. Not sure where to begin.....

Comment: You question is full of vague statements which makes it difficult to know how to help you. How do you know its "overloaded"? What do you mean exactly by "not allowing the application to be able to read"? How do you determine that? Does it crash? Does it produce too much output? Does it hang? What exactly?

Comment: Agree with `kaylum`. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . S.O. readers expect code, simple methods for testing, exact error messages. However, you may discover that Rpi Users on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ have encounter the same problem. Please don't post Q to the same forum, use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask a moderator to move it there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the vagueness. Was not sure if the issued was in Linux Bluetooth stack, Raspberry Pi, dongle, or elsewhere.

Switched out the Broadcom dongle with a Cambridge Silicon Radio and have eliminated all errors.

Thanks!